# How to add a graph to a CSV file?

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I have a folder with about 110 CSV files with multiple tables of data.

My plan is to create a VBA tool in an Excel file with a button which opens a dialogue box to choose a CSV file to open. In that opened file, I want to create graphs based on set ranges of cells (that don't vary throughout those 110 CSV files).

I am able to open CSV files and create graphs, but that graph is inserted in my standard Excel file, not the CSV file.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim my_FileName As Variant
my_FileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="CSV FILE,*.csv*;*.csv*")

If my_FileName <> False Then
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=my_FileName
End If

Dim rng As Range
Dim cht As Object

Set rng = my_FileName.Sheets(1).Range("D15:D86")
Set cht = my_FileName.Sheets(1).Shapes.AddChart2

cht.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=rng
cht.Chart.ChartType = xlXYScatterLines

End Sub
```

Comment: You're aware that you can't save a chart in a CSV file, right? But if you still want to proceed, `Dim wb As Workbook`, `Set wb = Workbooks.Open(my_FileName)`, `Set rng = wb.Sheets...`, `Set cht = wb.Sheets....`

Comment: @BigBen as Excel is so "friendly" to assign the CSV extension to Excel, many people think that CSV == Excel Files, where inserting a graph is certainly possible, even if saving it off is not.